# MERN API request, don't know how to make a put request and update properly

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

Let me first start by saying I am fairly new to  the MERN stack. I've been studying through tutorials, but some concepts are not explained very well.

When using GET, I call upon /users. However according to a tutorial, when I am posting, I have to post to /user/new. Not sure why it goes from plural (users) to singular (user). Is this a caveat with express, or am I creating a new route?

My biggest problem is that I do not know how to submit a PUT request... I can't update any of the information in my object. I'm also trying to add information into a sub array in my Animal model.

I will provide my App.js, server.js and Model(Animal),

SERVER.JS

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const twilio = require('twilio')

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/newtable', {
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true 
}).then(() => console.log("Connected to MongoDB")).catch(console.error);

app.listen(3008, () => console.log("Connected on Port 3008"));

const Animal = require('./models/Animals');

app.get('/animals', async(req, res) => {
    const animals = await Animal.find()
    res.json(animals)
})

app.post('/animals/new', (req, res) => {
    const animal = new Animal({
        phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber,
        textHistory: req.body.textHistory,
        name: req.body.name
    })
    animal.save()
    res.json(animal)
})

app.delete('/animal/delete/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const result = await Animal.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
    res.json({result});
});

app.put('/animal/update/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const numba = await Animal.findOne(req.params.id);
    numba.phoneNumber = "gordage"
    numba.save();
    res.json(numba);
    console.log('asdfoij')
})
```

ANIMAL.JS (model)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const AnimalSchema = new Schema({
    phoneNumber: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    textHistory: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    }
});

const Animal = mongoose.model("Animal", AnimalSchema);

module.exports = Animal;
```

App.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react"
import './App.css';


function App() {
  const api_base = "http://localhost:3008"
  const [animals, setAnimals] = useState([])

  const GetAnimals = () => {
    fetch(api_base + "/animals")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => setAnimals(data))
    .catch((err) => console.error("error", err));
    console.log(animals)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    GetAnimals()
  }, [])

  const deleteAnimal = async id => {
        const data = await fetch(api_base + '/animal/delete/' + id, { method: "DELETE" }).then(res => res.json());
        setAnimals(animals => animals.filter(animal => animal._id !== data.result._id));
    console.log('working')
    }

  const addAnimal = async () => {
        const data = await fetch(api_base + "/animals/new", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json" 
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                phoneNumber: "9175028901",
        textHistory: "benson",
        name: "beni"
            })
        }).then(res => res.json());

        setAnimals([...animals, data]);
    console.log("clicking")
    }

  const changePhone = async id => {
    const data = await fetch(api_base + '/animal/phoneNumber/' + id).then(res => res.json());
    console.log("doing")
    
    setAnimals(animals => animals.map(animal => {
      if (animal._id === data._id) {
        animal.phoneNumber = "bensonhurst";
      }
      return animal;
    }));
    console.log("doing")
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to Beni's Table</h1>
      <table className="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>One</th>
            <th>Two</th>
            <th>Three</th>
            <th>Four</th>
            <th>Five</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
      <h1>Animal List</h1>
      
        {animals.map(animal => (
          <tbody>
            <td>{animal.name}</td>
            <td>{animal._id}</td>
            <td>{animal.phoneNumber}</td>
            <button onClick={() => changePhone(animal._id)}>Change Phone</button>
            <button onClick={() => deleteAnimal(animal._id)}>X</button>
          </tbody>
        ))}
      
      <button onClick={addAnimal}>add</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You can use [postman](https://www.postman.com/) to assist you in sending any request to your server, there are other software you can explore

Comment: I am using REST client, still no luck.. I can't get a put request through. I think my syntax is wrong.

Comment: Do you mean your App.js? I do not see any method: "PUT"

Comment: GET /users - the API Get all users |
POST /user/new -  the API Create 1 new user

Basically why the tutorial use user not users

Answer (score 0):

How to submit PUT request from client side. I think this is the problem. You haven't specified method PUT in request in changePhone Method in react and on express the endpoint is /animal/update/:id and you are calling /animal/phoneNumber/. This is like communicating with server and in request Options we specify they hey "express server" I want to use PUT method so please update the data Just like you specified in POST. Also understanding what PUT method intuitively does would help you. ( It updates an existing data present based on id given by overwriting it which replaces original version of source )

So fixes for both would be :

Fetch PUT request in React :

```
const requestOptions = {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: { Animal: 'The data you want to change the exisiting data with' }
};
fetch(`/animal/update/${id}`, requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data));
```

PUT request in axios (Promise based http client):

```
const res = await axios.put(`/animal/update/${id}`, { Animal: 'The data you want to change the exisiting data with' });
```

This is client side Put request. Now for making Put method more clear on server side. Refer this : https://thecodepixi.dev/blog/express-mongoose-crud-api/#updating-instances.

Comment: Thanks for this. Any chance you know the syntax for mongoose? Also, where are you placing this Fetch PUT request? I still can't seem to get it going..

Comment: I'm running in to the same issue... Been stuck on this for like 2 days now.

Comment: Fetch put request should be placed based on choice. For example : A button with text update on click we make handler, and also send the whole modified data along with the put request in body. So what we do is send an id , server will search for that id , take our request body and replace it with new data. That's the gist of PUT method.  In mongoose just  google it you will find a lot of resources. Also shared a link in answer.

Comment: A user wants to edit the animal data of a particular id . On frontend he will click button edit. THen he will get a form or anything to update data. We will ask him hey add new data. He will enter it. We can collect that data. Track it in state. Make a onClick handler or submit button based on choice. ( Its all on choice like how you want frontend to be . I am just giving you inutuition oF PUT ) . Then fetch or axios put request will go to server. Server will update find data of that id and replace it with new one. Note : PATCH and PUT are different.

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html
Official doc for findOneandUpdate Mongoose syntax. This will be on server side endpoint which will update the data.

Comment: THank you for the detail.. It helps to understand but I still can't get anything to update :/

Comment: https://github.com/didinj/mern-stack-crud/blob/master/src/components/Edit.js Clienti side Code example MERN.

https://github.com/didinj/mern-stack-crud/blob/master/routes/book.js
Server side code example